# Grouping column by the first two characters into two groups

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I have this type of DF

```
DF
N   ID
1   0230
2   5902
3   2359
4   0530

DF
N   ID     GR
1   0230   1
2   5902   2
3   2359   1
4   3030   2
```

I would like to group column ID by the first two characters into two groups.
If first two characters are number lower than 30 is group 1 and higher than 30 and lower than 59 is group 2.

I would prefer dplyr solution.

I have tried this:

```
DF%>%
mutate(GR = ifelse(str(ID[2] >= 0 & DRG[2] < 31, 1, ifelse(str(ID[2] >= 31 & DRG[2] < 60, 0, "-" )))))
```

Comment: `GR = if_else(as.integer(str_sub(ID, 1, 2)) < 30L, 1, 2)`? (or: `str_extract(ID, "^\d{2}")`)

Comment: I works, thank you. Could I ask why there is "L" in condition?

Comment: It tells R that 30 is an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `dplyr` solution

```r
library(dplyr)
DF %>% 
  mutate(GR = case_when(
   as.numeric(ID) <= 3000 ~ 1,
   TRUE ~ 2)
  )

# A tibble: 4 x 3
      N ID       GR
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 0230      1
2     2 5902      2
3     3 2359      1
4     4 0530      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a math based solution,

```
(df$ID /(10^(nchar(df$ID)-2)) > 30 ) + 1
#[1] 1 2 1 2
```

**DATA:**

```
 dput(df)
structure(list(N = 1:4, ID = c(230L, 5902L, 2359L, 530L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `base R`solution:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  N = 1:4, ID = c("0230", "5902", "2359", "0530"))
```

Solution:

```
df$GR <- ifelse(as.numeric(sub("(\\d{2})(\\d{2})", "\\1", df$ID)) < 30 , 1, 2)
```

Here, we first define two regex capturing groups `(\\d{2})`and refer back to the first such group with `\\1` to extract it with `sub`, then we convert the result of  the extraction to type numeric, and finally we instruct `ifelse` to assign `1` and respectively `2` depending on the size of the extracted values:

Result:

```
df
  N   ID GR
1 1 0230  1
2 2 5902  2
3 3 2359  1
4 4 0530  1
```